# How can I round a signed integer up to zero?

Tags: objective-c, math, integer

I've been doing this everywhere

```
NSInteger myint = -3;

// ...

NSUInteger myuint = myint >= 0 ? myint : 0;
```

Is there a math function in Objective C that can do the same thing without using a ternary/conditional assignment? Something like this:

```
NSUInteger myuint = rounduptozero( myint );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use:

```
NSUInteger myuint = MAX(myint, 0);
```

or define your own `rounduptozero` function:

```
NSUInteger rounduptozero(NSInteger val) {
    return MAX(val, 0);
}

NSUInteger myuint = rounduptozero(mint);
```

Comment: Why can't I use an expression as one of the parameters, like `MAX(myint1 - myint2, 0)`? It just gives me a `NSNotFound`.

Comment: You can do that. Why don't you think you can?

Comment: When I try that, it gives me a `NSNotFound` value. But when I declare the same expression as a variable first, it works fine.

Comment: What are the datatypes and values of `myint1` and `myint2`?

Comment: `myint1` is an NSUInteger, and `myint2` is an NSInteger.

Comment: Depending on the values, it's dangerous to subtract signed and unsigned values. The result will be treated as unsigned so if the apparent result is negative you end up with a huge unsigned value.

Comment: Is there an inline way to convert an NSUInteger to an NSInteger?

Comment: Use a cast. But you need to be real careful.

Answer (score 0):

MAX is defined in the objective-c runtime (more specifically, it's in NSObjCRuntime, which is included in the Foundation framework), so you can safely use MAX(value, 0).

If you use it all over the place, I'd suggest wrapping that macro in your own (or in a function) for clarity.